# Differentiable But Not Continuous Example

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, continuity, definition, banach-spaces

In the context of maps between Banach spaces, a map $f:E\to F$ is differentiable at $x\in E $ *if* it is continuous at $ x $ and there exists a linear map $ T:E\to F $ such that $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\lVert f(x+h)-f(x)-Th\rVert}{\lVert h\rVert}=0.$$
The continuity assumption here then implies that the linear map $ T $ is bounded. Also, if one assumes in the definition that $ T $ is a bounded linear map, then $ f $ will be continuous at $x$.

I was wondering if someone had in mind an example of Banach spaces $ E, F $, a map $f:E\to F $, which isn't continuous at $ x\in E $, and an unbounded linear map $ T:E\to F $ such that $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\lVert f(x+h)-f(x)-Th\rVert}{\lVert h\rVert}=0.$$

Such an example would motivate the necessity of including either $ f$ continuous at $ x $ or $ T $ bounded in the definition of differentiability.

Comment: Let $f$ be an unbounded linear map. Then $f$ is not continuous, but at each $x$ differentiable with $Df(x) = f$.

Comment: That is, I think, the most optimal answer! But it leaves me wanting more. It would also be interesting if someone could come up with an example that doesn't have constant derivative. Do you have any intuition about this?

Comment: @R.Steven This is a new question. Never use comments to say "Okay,  I want more than I asked."

Comment: @martini This should be an official answer.

Comment: For the modified question, use the sum of an unbounded linear functional with a differentiable function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f \colon E \to F$ be an unbounded linear map. Then $f$ is not continuous, but differentiable with $Df(x) = f$ for each $x \in E$.

Comment: Perfect! This is the best answer to this question, I believe.